# Glassfish server showing Error 404, on the path where the page should be found

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jersey, glassfish

I am working on a web app using Intellij and Glassfish server. But, it is showing error 404, page not found. Specifically:

```text
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. I am doing this with Gradle.

I first made it using `web.xml` and then by extending `Application` but in both cases the result was same.

I tried the solutions from similar questions on SO, but none of them worked.

This is the RootResource code:

```java
package com.pd.jersey.jaxb;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
class RootResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

This is the Todo resource:

```java
package com.pd.jersey.jaxb;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Todo getXML() {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("Application XML Todo Summary");
        todo.setDescription("Application XML Todo Description");
        return todo;
    }

    // This method is called if JSON is requested
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Todo getJSON() {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("Application JSON Todo Summary");
        todo.setDescription("Application JSON Todo Description");
        return todo;
    }

    // This can be used to test the integration with the browser
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public Todo getHTML() {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("XML Todo Summary");
        todo.setDescription("XML Todo Description");
        return todo;
    }
}
```

This is the application code:

```java
package com.pd.jersey.jaxb;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    // All request scoped resources and providers
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(TodoResource.class);
        return classes;
    }

    // all singleton resources and providers
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of my run configuration:

[image: run-configuration]

I don't seem to find what's going wrong. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the wrong `Application`. The one you're using is for [*JavaFX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), which is for making graphical user interfaces. You need to extend [`javax.ws.rs.core.Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html).

Your question shows why you should ALWAYS use [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html) when you override a method; so you know you are actually overriding a method in the class (i.e. `getClasses()` and `getSingletons()`). If you added `@Override`, you would've seen that it isn't a method in the `Application` class you are using.